# VBA/EXCEL: Looping Through Cells With Conditional Formatting To Hide Rows Based on ColorIndex

Tags: excel, vba

I'm just starting to learn Macros and I'm trying to loop into conditionally formatted cells to look for a specific color which will then be hidden. Is there a way I could it in a loop? It should function like these:

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
        Range("A1").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
        Range("A2").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
        Range("A3").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by doing this:

```
For Each c In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A56")
     If c.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
     End If
Next c
```

Comment: You may need a `Next` to complete your loop.

Comment: and c.EntireRow.Hidden = false between for and if statments to initialize your range